# how to configure more than one static IP through programmatically using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, configuration, wmi

I have an application written in C# that needs to be able to configure the network adapters in Windows. I am able to configure one Static IP but I want more than one Static IP to work as expected

```
public void setIP(string ip_address, string subnet_mask)
    {
        ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
        {
            if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject setIP;
                    ManagementBaseObject newIP =
                        objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");

                    newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { ip_address };
                    newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnet_mask };

                    setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

This helps in configuring one static IP. but I want to configure more than 1 IP

Comment: I added the code for configure one static IP.

Comment: Thank-you good sir.  Here's a +1 :)   Wishing you well

Comment: Can you please share code for adding more than one static IP

Answer (score 1):

As your code already shows, the [EnableStatic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390383(v=VS.85).aspx) method has two string *array* parameters. This allows for setting multiple IP address/SubnetMask pairs. The documentation for the IP array says: 'Lists all of the static IP addresses for the current network adapter' and for the subnet mask: 'Subnet masks that complement the values in the IPAddress parameter'. So, code it like this:

```
  newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[]  { "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3" };
  newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { "255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.0" };
```